# Get a fully decorated sample stack trace for Xamarin Mono app on OS X

Tags: macos, xamarin, mono, stack, xamarin.mac

Running on OS X a debug/release mono app, via command line or Xamarin Studio, its possible to use Activity Monitor to take a sample. When I try this all managed code has had the function and assembly names removed, even though when building full debug info was specified.

Example sample output is;

```
Call graph:
2427 Thread_189745   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
+ 2427 start  (in mono) + 53  [0xc61f5]
+   2427 main  (in mono) + 1217  [0xc66c1]  .main.c:177
+     2427 mono_main  (in mono) + 8396  [0x155dac]  driver.g.c:1091
+       2427 mono_jit_exec  (in mono) + 213  [0x1538e5]  driver.g.c:1031
+         2427 mono_runtime_run_main  (in mono) + 632  [0x2b3898]  object.c:3837
+           2427 mono_runtime_exec_main  (in mono) + 401  [0x2b3ae1]  object.c:4223
+             2427 mono_runtime_invoke  (in mono) + 150  [0x2adb26]  object.c:2897
+               2427 mono_jit_runtime_invoke  (in mono) + 951  [0xd5487]  mini-runtime.c:2578
+                 2427 ???  (in <unknown binary>)  [0x6d3a4b]
+                   2427 ???  (in <unknown binary>)  [0x6d359c]
+                     2427 ???  (in <unknown binary>)  [0x1b6e41c]
+                       2427 ???  (in <unknown binary>)  [0xac32ae0]
+                         2427 ???  (in <unknown binary>)  [0xac32b94]
+                           2427 ves_icall_System_Threading_Thread_Sleep_internal  (in mono) + 97  [0x27e9a1]  threads.c:1181
+                             2423 mono_thread_info_sleep  (in mono) + 827  [0x33c39b]  .mono-os-mutex.h:134
+                             ! 2423 pthread_cond_timedwait$UNIX2003  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 71  [0x970b3d0b]
```

Is there anyway to run/build a mono app for OS X so that '???  (in unknown binary)' is populated with the expected assembly and function names? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Xamarin.Mac applications are JIT compiled, unlike Xamarin.iOS for example. From lldb's perspective, they are nonsense.

There is some information [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/) on how to debug mono with lldb/gdb, but I'm unsure it'll help here.

The [Xamarin profiler](https://www.xamarin.com/profiler) knows how handle this, but might not be accessible given that it requires an enterprise license.